# Shim use default method implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, microsoft-fakes, shim

Can I call default method from the inside of my **shim** somehow?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
ShimConfigurationHelper.GetConfigValueString = (key) {
    switch (key)
    {                       
        case "SpecialKey":
            return "some-value-for-testing";

        default:
            return ConfigurationHelper.GetConfigValue(key);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark off sections of your code to be executed as if they were outside of the ShimContext so that they will use the original implementation.  One way of doing this is to wrap the code in a delegate from a call to `ShimContext.ExecuteWithoutShims`.  Doing that, your code might look like this::

```
ShimConfigurationHelper.GetConfigValueString = (key) {
    var response=String.Empty;
    switch (key)
    {                       
        case "SpecialKey":
            response = "some-value-for-testing";
            break;

        default:
            ShimsContext.ExecuteWithoutShims(() => {
                response = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfigValue(key);
            });
            break;
    }
    return response;
};
```